# Solving recaptcha with anticaptcha using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, recaptcha

I am trying to fill recaptcha using [anticaptcha api](https://python-anticaptcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#solve-recaptcha).

But I am unable to figure out how to submit response.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe'))


site_key = '6Ldd2doaAAAAAFhvJxqgQ0OKnYEld82b9FKDBnRE'
api_key = 'api_keys'
url = 'https://coinsniper.net/register'

client = AnticaptchaClient(api_key)
task = NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask(url, site_key)
job = client.createTask(task)
job.join()

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').innerHTML='{}';".format(job.get_solution_response()))

driver.refresh()
```

Above code snippet only refreshes the same page and not redirecting to input url.

Then I see that there is a variable in script on the same page and I tried to execute that variable too to submit form just like that

```
driver.execute_script("var captchaSubmitEl = document.getElementById('captcha-submit');")

driver.refresh()
```

Which also fails.The webpage is [here](https://coinsniper.net/register).

Second try with this [url](https://geo.captcha-delivery.com/captcha/?initialCid=AHrlqAAAAAMABhLJ2Rn0V78AZ5gFAg%3D%3D&hash=7F23E8F8FB0B33347C06D1347938C1&cid=.z5o-mMJuvaX_CLxOMBRebJsY6NgZvUv87bLMft%7EA_st0Fkvl%7E3jcaTr1R64GU7xO.WZFYNq5P3.UNuLWFa32.Pe6GGuIV7Y5w-RaMu0K3&t=fe&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fcoinsniper.net%2Fregister&s=33682) which is loading recpatcha of the same page.

But this time I tried with different `site_key` and `url` which were extracted as below

```
url_key = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="captcha-submit"]/div/div/iframe').get_attribute('src')

site_key = re.search('k=([^&]+)',url_key).group(1)

url = 'https://geo.captcha-delivery.com/captcha/?initialCid=AHrlqAAAAAMABhLJ2Rn0V78AZ5gFAg%3D%3D&hash=7F23E8F8FB0B33347C06D1347938C1&cid=.z5o-mMJuvaX_CLxOMBRebJsY6NgZvUv87bLMft~A_st0Fkvl~3jcaTr1R64GU7xO.WZFYNq5P3.UNuLWFa32.Pe6GGuIV7Y5w-RaMu0K3&t=fe&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fcoinsniper.net%2Fregister&s=33682'

client = AnticaptchaClient(api_key)
task = NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask(url, site_key)
job = client.createTask(task)
job.join()

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').innerHTML='{}';".format(job.get_solution_response()))

driver.refresh()
```

Above both ways are, I don't know why but, not working. I am finding solution from previous 3 days and got not any single solution working in my case.

Can anyone look into this and let me know what is wrong with this code.

Comment: That's the wrong id, it should be `g-recaptcha-response-100000`, but that's not even in a form. Then there's another captcha to deal with. This one looks tricky, I don't think you're going to get it.

Comment: @pguardiario I have handled text captcha but I don't know how to get rid of captcha which is redirected to this [page](https://geo.captcha-delivery.com/captcha/?initialCid=AHrlqAAAAAMABhLJ2Rn0V78AZ5gFAg%3D%3D&hash=7F23E8F8FB0B33347C06D1347938C1&cid=.z5o-mMJuvaX_CLxOMBRebJsY6NgZvUv87bLMft%7EA_st0Fkvl%7E3jcaTr1R64GU7xO.WZFYNq5P3.UNuLWFa32.Pe6GGuIV7Y5w-RaMu0K3&t=fe&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fcoinsniper.net%2Fregister&s=33682)

Answer (score 2):

After you receive a response from anti-captcha you should set it to this element

```
<input type="hidden" class="mtcaptcha-verifiedtoken" name="mtcaptcha-verifiedtoken" id="mtcaptcha-verifiedtoken-1" readonly="readonly" value="">
```

Fill in all other fields on UI and click the Register button.
You should not refresh the page.

Comment: thanks for looking into it. The problem occur when that page redirected to this [one](https://geo.captcha-delivery.com/captcha/?initialCid=AHrlqAAAAAMABhLJ2Rn0V78AZ5gFAg%3D%3D&hash=7F23E8F8FB0B33347C06D1347938C1&cid=.z5o-mMJuvaX_CLxOMBRebJsY6NgZvUv87bLMft~A_st0Fkvl~3jcaTr1R64GU7xO.WZFYNq5P3.UNuLWFa32.Pe6GGuIV7Y5w-RaMu0K3&t=fe&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fcoinsniper.net%2Fregister&s=33682)

Comment: ReCaptcha could be solved with the same approach. But after filling the hidden input instead of clicking on the Register button - click on the Recaptcha checkbox.

Comment: When I click on that checkbox after filling in `textarea` with `execute_script`,it pops-up with challenge to resolve.

Comment: You may try to figure out how it's working using JS in that page source. It is not obfuscated. 
You may also try to submit elements instead of clicking them.

Comment: Still not getting any luck. Will you try it?

Comment: This question is about 'I am not robot' captcha challenge not for text captcha. Hope you're getting my point!